# Matrices with left and right singular vectors being vandermonde matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Assume we have matrices ${\bf H_i}$ for $i\in[1:K]$ and that the Singluar Value Decomposition (SVD) of ${\bf H_i}$ is such that

$${\bf  H_i = A_{bi} D_iA_{si}^*}$$

where ${\bf A_{bi}}$ and $ {\bf A_{si}}$ are vandermonde matrices and are the matrices of the left and right singular vector (described below) and ${\bf D_i}$ is a diagonal matrix .

[Vandermonde matrix wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

More precisely

${\bf A_{bi}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 &  \\
    e^{j\phi_{1i}} &   e^{j\phi_{2i}} & e^{j\phi_{3i}} &\\
    e^{j2\phi_{1i}} &   e^{j2\phi_{2i}} & e^{j2\phi_{3i}} \\
    e^{j3\phi_{1i}} &   e^{j3\phi_{2i}} & e^{j3\phi_{3i}} & \\
    e^{j4\phi_{1i}} &   e^{j4\phi_{2i}} & e^{j4\phi_{3i}} & \\
  e^{j5\phi_{1i}} &   e^{j5\phi_{2i}} & e^{j5\phi_{3i}} & \\
  \end{bmatrix}$
${\bf A_{si}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 &  \\
    e^{j\theta_{1i}} &   e^{j\theta_{2i}} & e^{j\theta_{3i}} &\\
    e^{j2\theta_{1i}} &   e^{j2\theta_{2i}} & e^{j2\theta_{3i}} \\
    e^{j3\theta_{1i}} &   e^{j3\theta_{2i}} & e^{j3\theta_{3i}} & \\
    e^{j4\theta_{1i}} &   e^{j4\theta_{2i}} & e^{j4\theta_{3i}} & \\
  e^{j5\theta_{1i}} &   e^{j5\theta_{2i}} & e^{j5\theta_{3i}} & \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

So basically the above matrices have entries $[\bf A_{is}]$ and $[\bf A_{ib}]$ that are complex exponentials (phase shifts) with magnitude equal to one.

My question is next, assume we have formed a concatenated matrix $${\bf H= [{\bf H_1},{\bf H_2},{\bf H_3}, \cdots, {\bf H_K}]}$$ using the matrces ${\bf H_i}$ described above.

Is it safe to say that the right and left singluar values of ${\bf H}$ are also vandermonde matrices and are phase shifts (exponentials) where the entries are of constant magnitude equal to one ..?

Any hints for such a proof if this is true

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $A_{bi}$ is not a unitary matrix. That is
$$
A_{bi}^{*} A_{bi} \ne I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.  Similarly, $A_{si}$ is not a unitary matrix. Thus, the SVD of $H_i$ is NOT given by 
$$
H_i = A_{bi} D_i A_{si}^{*}
$$
as claimed. Please edit your question and resubmit.